# How to align Fontastic.me icons properly like text?

Tags: html, css, materialize, fontastic

I'm using fontastic.me (Custom icons CSS) to display some social icons with MaterializeCSS. I can't get it aligned properly. As shown in images below.

[image: Materialize FAB, the icons aren't in center]

[image: Text and Icon not aligned properly]

1) Materialize FAB, the icons aren't in center

2) Text and Icon not aligned properly

Could anyone help me with aligning these correctly?

```html
<div class="fixed-action-btn">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large red"><i class="large icon icon-share"></i></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="large icon icon-whatsapp"></i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="large icon icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="btn waves-light waves-effect green"><i class="icon icon-whatsapp"></i> WhatsApp</button>
```

Comment: Just taking a casual stab in the dark here, since there are no relevant styles to refer to or consider; have you tried adjusting the `line-height` of the icons in question?

Comment: A simple fix would be to apply something like `.btn .icon { position: relative; top: 5px; }`. If you don't like this approach; play around with the properties `vertical-align` and `line-height`.

Comment: `.btn .icon { position: relative; top: 5px; }` Didn't work.

Comment: Building on the cornerstones @JasonK has laid down, you could declare `position: relative` on the containing element of the icons (the circle), make sure they have an explicit `width` and `height` defined, then declare `position: absolute` on the nested icon elements, give them a `height` and `top` and `bottom` properties with values of `0`, then declare `margin: auto` and `display: block`. Difficult to demonstrate without a full deck of cards to work with, but I hope that clear enough.